# Merging two data frames with origins

Tags: python, pandas, merge, merging-data

Suppose I have the two following data frames df_1 and df_2 and want to merge them with an additional column which states if the row is present in df_1,df_2 or both. Is there any way I could do this directly while using merge?

df_1

[image: Data Frame 1]

df_2

[image]

The data frame I would like to have:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameter `indicator` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and for expected output add [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator='origin')
print (df)
   Index   x  y      origin
0     20   5  8   left_only
1     35   4  7   left_only
2     55   3  2        both
3     60  12  1        both
4     22   4  3  right_only
5     30  12  6  right_only

d = {'left_only':'1', 'right_only':'2', 'both':'1 & 2'}
df['origin'] = df['origin'].map(d)
print (df)
   Index   x  y origin
0     20   5  8      1
1     35   4  7      1
2     55   3  2  1 & 2
3     60  12  1  1 & 2
4     22   4  3      2
5     30  12  6      2
```